# Why is RadioButton returning NULL?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have a dialog with 4 `RadioButton`s in a `RadioGroup` and am trying to return the ID of the button clicked but I keep getting a `NullPointerException`. I've looked at several examples and don't see how mine differs.

```
    <RadioGroup
             android:id="@+id/radiojqmobdiv"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:checkedButton="0"
             android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/jqpage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/jqpage" 
                android:checked="true" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/jqheader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/jqheader" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/jqcontent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/jqcontent" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/jqfooter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/jqfooter" />

        </RadioGroup>
```

Code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);

        et = (EditTextLineNumbers) findViewById(R.id.ide);
        et.setTextColor(preferences.getInt("colourChoice", Color.GREEN));
        et.setMaxLines(5000);
        divBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divbutton);
        divGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiojqmobdiv);

        exists = false;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webpreview);
        web.setOnClickListener(this);
        web.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/My Webs");
        currentDirectory = dir;
        ListView lv = getListView();
        registerForContextMenu(lv);
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                Show_Alert_box(v.getContext(), "Please select action.",
                        position);
                return false;
            }
        });

        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                changed = true;
                startPos = et.getSelectionStart();
                endPos = et.getSelectionEnd();
            }
        });
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            browseToRoot();
        } else {
            dir.mkdir();
        }

        divBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.divdialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Inserv Div");

                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                // TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                // text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
                // ImageView image = (ImageView)
                // dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                // image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                **Button insertButton = (Button) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.insertBtn);**
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                insertButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // int selectedID = divGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                        // find the radiobutton by returned id
                        divRdoBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedID);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, divRdoBtn.getText(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
                cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }

        });

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        loadPrefs();
    }
```

Comment: divGroup is initialised onCreate(); the NullException happens on  int selectedID ...

Comment: Then `divGroup` is `null`

Comment: Do the RadioButtons need to be added programmatically to the group?

Comment: Where is `divGroup` initialized?

Comment: I see. I assume you call `setContentView()` before  `divGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiojqmobdiv);` and the `layout` in `setContentView()` is the `layout` that contains `radiojqmobdiv`?

Comment: Yes. I'll make a larger edit to reflect that.

Comment: @RapsFan1981 : Don't just edit code to have `...` in it. Show the actual code.

Comment: Where do you declare and initialize your `insertButton`?

Comment: I declare and initialize it right before I add the listener.

Comment: Ok, where is this `divButton` in your `Layout`? Have you set a breakpoint to see which object is null?` Why do you have listeners inside of listeners? Declare your buttons and set the listeners in onCreate(). If you explain what you are trying to accomplish then it may be easier to help. To be honest, it looks kind of messy

Comment: divBtn is in R.layout.main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the full xml files of both your dialog layout and your activity layout, so I'm  making some assumptions here.

However, you said in your title that the **Dialog** contains the RadioGroup that you have named divGroup. If that is true, it makes sense that you would not be able to find the RadioGroup when you execute this line:

```
divGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiojqmobdiv);
```

You are searching in the Activity for the id R.id.radiojqmobdiv, which you have implied exists only in the dialog that you haven't created yet. findViewById() returns null if the view isn't found, so you are assigning null to `divGroup`.

You should move that line down after you declare the dialog, and make sure you call `findViewById` on your `dialog` object instead of on the Activity.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.divdialog);
divGroup = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radiojqmobdiv);
```

Comment: Ahhhtesting now but I have a feeling this will work it makes sense

Comment: Good! :) Let me know if it works or if I can add to the answer to help more.